# MySQL Job failed to start

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I'm on Kubuntu 12.04, and after installing mysql via an apt-get (mysql ver: 5.5.35), i'm trying to start mysql service, but I got this error:

> sudo service mysql start
>
> start: Job failed to start

So I googled this problem, it says i have to go to the /var/log/mysql/error.log

But my error.log file is empty :(

Then I checked the permissions
:

> drwxr-s---  2 mysql  adm     4096 Apr  7 11:21 mysql
>
> -rw-r----- 1 mysql adm    0 Apr  7 11:21 error.log

So I don't know what to do... Why this error ? Why is the error file empty ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

First make a backup of your /var/lib/mysql/ directory just to be safe.

```
sudo mkdir /home/<your username>/mysql/
cd /var/lib/mysql/
sudo cp * /home/<your username>/mysql/ -R
```

Next purge MySQL (this will remove php5-mysql and phpmyadmin as well as a number of other libraries so be prepared to re-install some items after this.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1 mysql-common
```

Remove the folder /etc/mysql/ and it's contents

```
sudo rm /etc/mysql/ -R
```

Next check that your old database files are still in /var/lib/mysql/ if they are not then copy them back in to the folder then chown root:root

(only run these if the files are no longer there)

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql/
sudo chown root:root /var/lib/mysql/ -R
cd ~/mysql/
sudo cp * /var/lib/mysql/ -R
```

Next install mysql server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Finally re-install any missing packages like phpmyadmin and php5-mysql.

Comment: what would be the reason of such a crash ? mysql is pretty stable… It happened to me

Comment: @Ben :This problem may be occurred due to improper installation or uninstall .If you are installed first time in your system it will not occur . There might be some  dependencies that are not properly  removed completely when you re-installing mysql.

Comment: I'm very proccupied then..  my mysql install was running for like more than a year, i've upgraded ubuntu then the mysql to 5.5 about a month ago. Never had any problems. Meaning someone made his way into my server you think ?

Comment: @Ben :After you upgraded ubuntu did you installed mysql once again ?

Comment: I upgraded all the packages (don't remember the command). But not explicitly mysql by itself. My worry is that it had been running like this for more than a month

Comment: Just do the `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1 mysql-common` followed by `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Have people realized that just rebooting might solve this issue? It worked for me and I think it should be the first attempt before performing these steps.

Comment: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)` when `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. Should have tried rebooting first...

Comment: After I finally solved all the issues and succesfully reinstalled `mysql-server`, I found that my data have all lost!!! The data I have copied via `sudo cp * /home/<your username>/mysql/ -R` is the same with `/var/lib/mysql/`, which is of no usage. This is a very dangerous and bad answer!

Comment: REMEMBER  to use `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` if server not upgraded, because `att-get install mysql-server` will trigg many errors if not consistent... That was my problem.

Comment: will my existing databases be safe ?

Comment: I had same problem for mysql 5.7 and worked properly too, no databases lost, thanks @Rajesh

Answer (score 10):

My problem was running out of memory. Digital ocean has great instruction for adding swap memory for Ubuntu: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

This solved the issue and enabled me to restart the Mysql that otherwise would not start.

Answer (score 6):

Reinstallation will works because it will reset all the value to default. It is better to find what the real culprits (my.cnf  editing mistake does happens, e.g. bad/outdated parameter suggestion during mysql tuning.)

Here is the mysql diagnosis if you suspect some value is wrong inside my.cnf  : Run the mysqld to show you the results.

```
sudo -u mysql  mysqld
```

Afterwards, fix all the my.cnf key error that pop out from the screen until mysqld startup successfully.

Then restart it using

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it simply because the disk is full.
Just clear some disk space and restart and everything is fine.

Comment: In my case too. Thanks.

Comment: Idem. You saved me from a valley of tears. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, just purging the mysql-server package and re-installing it will do the job.

Run,

`sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1 mysql-common`

followed by

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 2):

This line did solve the issue in my case,

```
sudo apt clean
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i do:

1. `sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. search for `bind` names and IPs
3. remove the specific, and let only localhost 127.0.0.1 and the hostname

Comment: How do i search bind ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file permissions, if edited

Fail:

```
$ sudo chmod 776 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
$ sudo service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start
```

Ok:

```
$ sudo chmod 774 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
$ sudo service mysql restart
stop: Unknown instance:
mysql start/running, process 9564
```

Answer (score 1):

To help others who do not have a full disk to troubleshoot this problem, first inspect your error log (for me the path is given in my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file):

```
tail /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

My problem turned out to be a new IP address allocated after some network router reconfiguration, so I needed to change the `bind-address` variable.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the `/var/log` disk full (check with `df -h`)

Just deleted some log files and mysql started, no big deal!

Answer (score 0):

The given solution requires enough free HDD, the actual problem was the HDD memory shortage. So If you don't have an alternative server or free disk space, you need some other alternative.

I faced this error with my production server (Linode VPS) when I was running a bulk download into MySQL. Its not a proper solution but VERY QUICK FIX, which we often need in production to bring things UP FAST.

1. Resize our VPS Server to higher Hard Disk size
2. Start MySQL, it works.
3. Login to your MySQL instance and make appropriate adjustments that caused this error (e.g. remove some records, table, or take DB backup to your local machine that are not required at production, etc. After all you know, what caused this issue.)
4. Downgrade your VPS Server to previous package you was already using

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

- restart server
- restart mysql
- create .socket in directory

Comment: please have more details, where to create .socket directory

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But i discover that my hd is full.

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/upstart/mysql.log
/proc/self/fd/9: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
```

So, I run

```
$ df -h
```

And I got the message

```
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  7.4G     0 100% /
```

Then I found out which folder was full by running the following command on the terminal

```
$ cd /var/www
$ for i in *; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done
```

This give me the number of files on each folder on /var/www. I logged into the folder with most files, and deleted some backup files, and i continued deleting useless files and cache files.

then I run $ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start and it work again