# ERROR: There's not enough space in /var/lib/mysql/

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql.sock

I am exactly with the problem of the following question on my server and when accessing the log file it appears empty, i.e., no information.

[MySQL Job failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909060/mysql-job-failed-to-start)

Data from my server:

```
ricardoramos@garapa:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

I have only ssh access to my server. In addition, I have already performed all the steps suggested by `@Rajesh`, however when reinstalling `mysql-server` with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

I get the following message:

```
ERROR: There's not enough space in /var/lib/mysql/

E: Write error - write (28: There is no space available on the device)

ricardoramos@garapa:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disco /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000202305536 bytes
255 cabeças, 63 setores/trilhas, 121601 cilindros, total de 1953520128 setores
Unidades = setores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho do setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho da E/S (mínimo/ideal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificador do disco: 0x471b256c

Dispositivo Boot Início Fim Blocos Id Sistema
/dev/sda1   *         128  1603201151   801600512   83  Linux
/dev/sda2      1603201152  1953517951   175158400    5  Estendida
/dev/sda5      1603201280  1945706751   171252736   83  Linux
/dev/sda6      1945706880  1953517951     3905536   82  Linux swap / Solaris


ricardoramos@garapa:~$ df -h
Sist. Arq.      Tam. Usado Disp. Uso% Montado em
/dev/sda5       163G  155G     0 100% /
udev            1,5G  4,0K  1,5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           599M  724K  599M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,5G     0  1,5G   0% /run/shm
overflow        1,0M  1,0M     0 100% /tmp
/dev/sda1       759G  4,1G  717G   1% /home

ricardoramos@garapa:~$ dpkg -l | grep mysql
iU  libdbd-mysql-perl                      4.020-1ubuntu0.1                           Perl5 database interface to the MySQL database
ii  libmysql-java                          5.1.16-2                                   Java database (JDBC) driver for MySQL
iU  libmysqlclient18                       5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    MySQL database client library
iU  mysql-client-5.5                       5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-5.5                  5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    MySQL database core client binaries
ii  mysql-common                           5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ii  mysql-gui-tools-common                 5.0r14+openSUSE-2.2ubuntu2                 Architecture independent files for MySQL GUI Tools
iU  mysql-server                           5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-core-5.5                  5.5.54-0ubuntu0.12.04.1                    MySQL database server binaries
```

Also, I already checked the following question in askubuntu, but I still have no solution.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/482923/mysql-error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full

How should I do to get the MySQL server installed?

Answer (score 1):

Change the data directory path for mysql as your root directory 100% used.
You have space(717G) in your /home directory

To change the Path follow the steps :
[How to change MySQL data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795176/how-to-change-mysql-data-directory)

Comment: Hello @Jaiprakash, you say what directory of mysql? Could you please detail it? It is just which directory I should move that I am in doubt.

Comment: move /var/lib/mysql/ to /home/new-directory-name  and chown new-directory-name to mysql user and group.

Comment: Hello @Jaiprakash, I ran the following commands `sudo mv /var/lib/mysql/  /home/mysql/` and `sudo chown mysql: mysql /home/mysql/`
but the `/var/lib/mysql/` folder is still in the same place, should I delete it? I tried installing `mysql-server`, but the same error message is appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `sudo mv /var/lib/mysql  /home`   to move the folder and `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql`  to change owner and user group here is another link [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-change-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-using-a-symlink]   And also reboot  your system or remove temporary file before executing the commands

Answer (score 1):

Probably the hard drive device your your "var" folder is allocated is full filled. You can try to create a symbolic link to your user directory:

```
mkdir ~/mysql
```

And then create a symbolic link:

```
cd /var/lib
sudo rm -rf mysql
sudo ln -s /home/$USER/mysql ./mysql
```

Finally, try to re-install mysql-server-5.5.